# Where is JBOSS_HOME variable set for Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss, environment-variables

So I'm trying to run JBoss server in Intellij, but there's a **conflict** between JBOSS_HOME path that Intellij reads from somewhere and the actual path to Jboss folder that is set in **Run/Debug Configuration**.

The  **Run/Debug Configuration** Jboss path used to be the same as JBOSS_HOME, but it has changed, and it looks like JBOSS_HOME didn't get updated.

There is no environmental variable called JBOSS_HOME, so I guess Intellij stores it's own variables somewhere.

[image: Error describind the conflict]

I've already checked **File->Settings->Appearance & Behaviour->Path Variables**
but there's no JBOSS_HOME variable set. I've tried restarting Intellij with no luck.

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are set individually per each application server defined, be it JBoss, Tomcat or something else. You can access and create/modify/remove them in 2 ways:

1. `File` -> `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Application servers`

[image: Application servers config window]

2. From the `Run/Debug configuration window`. From the dropdown list in your upper right corner where the run/debug buttons are, select `Edit configurations...`, select your JBoss run configuration from the tree on the left and click on the `Config` button (which will open a window pretty much identical to the one at point 1.)

[image: Run/DEbug configuration window]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I am gonna check it as soon as I get back to my work

Comment: Ok, it kind of helped resolve the issue, which happened to be some directories mess in our project, so upvote

Comment: Thanks and Worked ! You deserve an upvote !